# Can't access an internal IIS web site via IP address, only hostname

Tags: home-networking, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I have a machine on my home network running Windows Server 2008 (IIS7) with a web application running under default website called HTCOMNET. The network is just on a Windows Workgroup. The server is named nas1 and has a (dynamically assigned) IPv4 address of 192.168.2.12.

I can ping 192.168.2.12. When I ping the machine by name ("nas1"), the hostname resolves to an IPv6 link-local address (as opposed to the ipv4 address). In a browser, I can go to http://nas1/HTCOMNET/ and IIS serves the site, no problem. But if I go to http://192.168.2.12/HTCOMNET, no dice. I have all the windows firewalls turned off.

Any idea what's going on? I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't hit IIS via the IP. I feel like it's something really obvious, but i can't figure out what. Thanks!

Comment: When you load the ip in the browser what error shows up?

Comment: I just get a typical "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. No IIS error or anything.

Comment: What happens if you try to go to http: //[ipv6 address]/HTCOMNET (with the brackets) from another computer?

Answer (score 2):

[Check to see if your bindings are correct](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28WS.10%29.aspx) for what you are trying to do.  You should add all unassigned addresses to the web site you are trying to serve.

Comment: No dice, but thanks for pointing that out. The binding was already in place for * ip addresses to go to port 80.